# php - get how many available ads from table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this table `advertisements`, where I store all my advertisements. Everytime a user clicks on an advertisement, I record that click into a table called `advertisement_clicks`.

What I store in both tables is: `userid` and a `unique token`.

So, I want to count how many available advertisements there is for the user to see. Currently, I am doing it like this:

```
    $ex = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM advertisements WHERE status='2' AND fixed='0'");
    $ex->execute();


foreach ($ex as $normal) {
    $search2=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM advertisement_clicks WHERE token=:token AND username=:username");
    $search2->bindParam(":token",$normal['token']);
    $search2->bindParam(":username",$userdata['id']);
    $search2->execute();
}


$allnormal = $ex->rowCount();
$clickednormal = $search2->rowCount();
$normalads = $allnormal-$clickednormal;



$allnormal = how many advertisements is available.
$clickednormal = how many of these advertisements has the user clicked.
```

So the above approach is a bit messy and it doesn't give the correct result.

Can someone help me do this a smarter way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use COUNT to get it through SQL instead.

> SELECT count(*) as addCount FROM advertisement_clicks WHERE
>        token=:token AND username=:username"

Answer (score 0):

I havn't messed with php in a while so I'm not going to even attempt to write some code lol, but the way I did it was I executed this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM advertisement_clicks WHERE token=:token AND username=:username
```

Then get the query result which will return the advertisement count.